# How to get individual product related images in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to get each product related images which is not assign to product but want to show all related images in front-end.

[image]

```
<?php
foreach ($data['product'] as $product) { 

                            $product_id                 =   $product->getId();
                            $product_name               =   $product->getName();
                            $product_description        =   $product->getDescription();
                            $product_price        =   $product->getPrice();

                            $isporductImage     =   $product->getImage();
                            $product_image      =   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" . $product->getImage();
                            $isproductthumbnail = $product->getThumbnail();
                            $product_thumbnail  =   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" . $product->getThumbnail();
                            $collectionimage    = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/category/thumb/" . $data['collection']['image'];
                            $productplaceholderImage = $this->getSkinUrl() . "whi/assets/images/whi_placeholder.png";


                        ?>

                        <?php if ($isproductthumbnail != "") { ?>
                                  <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $product_thumbnail;?>');">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $product_thumbnail; ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                  </div>

                          <?php }elseif ($isporductImage != "") { ?>
                                  <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $product_image;?>');">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                  </div>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                    <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $productplaceholderImage;?>');">     
                                      <img src="<?php echo $productplaceholderImage ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                    </div>

                            <?php } ?>
```

i want to show all related product images in this list.

```
 <ul class="outfit-images-cmt">
                <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/doll.png"></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/doll.png"></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/doll.png"></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/doll.png"></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for fetch all the gallery images:

```
$product_image_url_gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
$galleryURL = '';
echo '<ul class="outfit-images-cmt">';

foreach ($product_image_url_gallery as $image) {
  $galleryImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile());
   echo '<li><img src="'.$galleryURL.'"></li>'
}

echo '</ul>';
```